# "composeEnhancers" is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting the below error in my code:

```
TypeError: composeEnhancers is not a function
```

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));
```

Can anyone see where the issue lies here? I don't understand as I have just copied my ReactJS instructor's code and he doesn't get this error, yet I do.

My whole code is shown here:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import burgerBuilderReducer from './store/reducers/burgerBuilder';
import orderReducer from './store/reducers/order';
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';

const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    burgerBuilder: burgerBuilderReducer,
    order: orderReducer,
    auth: authReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render( app, document.getElementById( 'root' ) );
registerServiceWorker();
```

A more descriptive error (in the browser's console) shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: composeEnhancers is not a function
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2dae6e05073e9d71bfd6:698)
    at fn (bootstrap 2dae6e05073e9d71bfd6:111)
    at Object.0 (order.js:59)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2dae6e05073e9d71bfd6:698)
    at bootstrap 2dae6e05073e9d71bfd6:796
    at bootstrap 2dae6e05073e9d71bfd6:796
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are likely running your app in dev mode in a browser that doesn't have Redux DevTools installed.

The problem is in this line:

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;
```

Due to operator precedence rules, this is equivalent to:

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : (null || compose);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
let composeEnhancers = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__;
} else {
    composeEnhancers = compose;
}
```

So, if you are in dev mode and you don't have Redux DevTools extension installed in your browser, your app will break, because `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` is not defined.
What you really need is this:

```
let composeEnhancers = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
} else {
    composeEnhancers = compose;
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
const composeEnhancers = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null) || compose;
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly!!!! It was broken in safari and worked on chrome but its probable that the user don't have redux devtools installed

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, i run the localhost:3000 in Incognito and got this error, when i switch to my chrome account with redux dev tool installed, it works

Comment: LOL! I had this exact same error from the same problem and course. Instructor asked me to compare my code with his, but did not raise this potential issue! THat's exactly the problem and I very much thank you for adding this solution!

Answer (score 1):

2020 update

---

With Elvis (or safe navigation) operator that was introduced in TypeScript 3.8 it's possible to simplify it and make it look much better. Like below:

```
const composeEnhancers =
  (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
    (window as any)?.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;
```

What it means is:

- elvis operator checks if `window?.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` is defined
- if it not exist it evaluates to `undefined` so first part of code returns false (if we are in development mode -> true && undefined = false) and fallback evaluates

Comment: Cannot find name 'window'. where i could import this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const composeEnhancers = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && typeof window !== 'undefined' )?window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose: compose;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have had the same problem and Yes your problem is in this line of your code.

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;
```

if you just install the Redux devtools extension on your browser you will notice that the browser will show you your app smoothly, this means the code above is not doing it's work correctly like it's expected to do, that's because of the operator precedence rules. just use the more simple and understandable `IF statements`  so that you as a beginner can also understand what is the code doing.
the code bellow will work just fine and it's very easy to understand.

```
let composeEnhancers = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
   composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
} else {
   composeEnhancers = compose;
}
```