# After deploying on GH pages the app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have such problem, after deploying my React app on GitHub it works only in my PC. When I open link where is my App have to be deployed using my PC or LapTop [link](https://dmitriykulikovskiy.github.io/MyWeatherForecast/#/Home) - it works, but when I tried to open it with phone or send this link to my friend - there is empty page (with my background). So how to solve this problem?

There is my repository [link](https://github.com/DmitriyKulikovskiy/MyWeatherForecast)

Code of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "worktests",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://dmitriykulikovskiy.github.io/MyWeatherForecast",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deploying from `gh-pages`?

Comment: @AkshataMohanty yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this [line](https://github.com/DmitriyKulikovskiy/MyWeatherForecast/blob/53c94d9702cec8f7feab754b58b1bb0ea6ac3b11/src/redux/store.jsx#L30):

`const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` in `store.jsx`

`window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` is only available if you have Redux Web Tools installed on your browser. Your app didn't run for me locally either. However, once I installed the extension, it ran correctly both locally as well as on your deployed site.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628279/composeenhancers-is-not-a-function-in-reactjs) thread might help find the right way to use `composeEnhancers` in production. Ideally, in production, you shouldn't be depending on properties populated by the dev tool plugin for debugging but you should be using `compose` directly from `redux`.