# blank page when deploying react-app into firebase hosting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-hosting, react-thunk

i have a problem related to deploying my react-app into firebase hosting , my react app is created with create-react-app, the build folder is ready and and i have successfully deployed my app to firebase , but nothing shows up , here is my firebase.json file

[firebase.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmyZL.png)

here is the error in the browser :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2IRC.png)

the app was working just fine in my computer localhost
anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have redux devtools installed on your browser?

Comment: yes , i have redux devtools installed, like i said everything was working fine in my local host, but when i deployed , the content dont show up , so i find this solution for the error in the browser : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628279/composeenhancers-is-not-a-function-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove any comments without brackets, jsx works fine with them in production mode but not in build mode.